# generate array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to generate an array from data set. I want my array to be with 2 columns, but the problem my file is including a first column of the index which I want to ignore.

The data set looks like this:

```
1   8.9 -8.536
2   10.2    5
```

I want to generate an array with only the points, like `[8.9,-8.536]` and to ignore the first column which is the index.

My code is as following, I think it works if there is no the column index, how I can make it work and ignore the first column?

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    w, h = [float(x) for x in f.readline().split()] # read first line
     array = []
     for line in f: # read rest of lines
         array.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
print array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use a slice to get the part of the list you want!

```
 for line in f: # read rest of lines
     array.append([float(x) for x in line.split()[1:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice the array with `[1:]`; this will drop the first element:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    array = []
    for line in f: # read rest of lines
        array.append([float(x) for x in line.split()[1:]])

print array
```

or even better:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    array = [[float(x) for x in line.split()[1:]] for line in f]
```